# Quickest way to update an object's value in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Trying to find out the quickest way to update an object's value in the array.

1. You wouldn't know the exact position, hence doing `animes[0]readStatus=true` is not possible
2. I'm trying to avoid for loop as the array may be A LOT. Example 1 million. Though it seems that for loop is faster, tested by someone and posted [here in Medium](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array-in-javascript-a49b108404c)

Following is my solution to tackle this, could you suggest something better?

```
const animes = [
  {
    id:'1',
    title:'latest anime',
    readStatus:false,
    imageSource:'https://help.twitter.com/content/dam/help-twitter/twitter-logo.png'
  },
  {
    id:'2',
    title:'naruto',
    readStatus:true,
    imageSource:'https://mapstr-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/298ed6c57ada2a7560d24dabba452548_facebook-logo-F-1200x816.jpg'
  },
    {
    id:'3',
    title:'one piece',
    readStatus:true,
    imageSource:'https://mapstr-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/298ed6c57ada2a7560d24dabba452548_facebook-logo-F-1200x816.jpg'
  },
    {
    id:'4',
    title:'you name it',
    readStatus:true,
    imageSource:'https://mapstr-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/298ed6c57ada2a7560d24dabba452548_facebook-logo-F-1200x816.jpg'
  }
]

let rebels = animes.filter((anime) => {
  return anime.id === '1';
});

let newItems = animes.filter((anime) => {
  return anime.id !== '1';
});


let myMap = Object.assign({}, rebels)
myMap[0].readStatus = true;
newItems.push(myMap[0])
console.log(newItems);
```

Comment: The real question is, why would you even load an array with a million entries on the client side.

Comment: @Terry 'A million' entries is just being exaggeration here. I thought for loop may not be wise to use

Comment: Because returning a million records to a user is not useful.  It is over whelming

Comment: well only way is to loop to find the index. Either for loop or find or make a map.

Comment: But aside from that, mapping your array to an object, where they keys are the `id` of the nested objects, would allow you to do quick look ups from that point on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with an array, a loop is the best way to find something. If it's a million items, sounds like you need to consider your database strategy!

But that aside, here's how I would do it:

```js
const animes = [
  {
    id:'1',
    title:'latest anime',
    readStatus:false,
    imageSource:'https://help.twitter.com/content/dam/help-twitter/twitter-logo.png'
  },
  {
    id:'2',
    title:'naruto',
    readStatus:true,
    imageSource:'https://mapstr-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/298ed6c57ada2a7560d24dabba452548_facebook-logo-F-1200x816.jpg'
  },
    {
    id:'3',
    title:'one piece',
    readStatus:true,
    imageSource:'https://mapstr-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/298ed6c57ada2a7560d24dabba452548_facebook-logo-F-1200x816.jpg'
  },
    {
    id:'4',
    title:'you name it',
    readStatus:true,
    imageSource:'https://mapstr-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/298ed6c57ada2a7560d24dabba452548_facebook-logo-F-1200x816.jpg'
  }
]

function markAsRead(id) {
  const idx = animes.findIndex(a => a.id === id);
  if (idx > -1) {
    animes.splice(idx, 1, { ...animes[idx], readStatus: true });
  }
}

markAsRead('1');

console.log(animes);
```

Comment: I have to admit, I was being exaggeration with my question for saying A Million records will be stored in the array. As mentioned on the comment earlier, I thought it may not be wise to use for loop to update the object's value. Thanks for the suggestion, it does better job than mine (:

Answer (score 2):

```
const animeById = animes.reduce((all, anime) => { all[anime.id] = anime; return all; }, {});
```

You can construct a secondary object with the ids as the key, and then use that going forward for fast lookups.

Comment: It's worth noting that aside from the insignificant extra intitial processing required to add this object, it should be maintained everytime elements are added to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Am i late to join the party?

As JS's array is storing a list of references, the easiest way is to find the first matching object, and update it straight away.
This will alter the original object from the list itself.
There is no need to modify / recreate the list.

```js
const animes = [
  {
    id:'1',
    title:'latest anime',
    readStatus:false,
    imageSource:'https://help.twitter.com/content/dam/help-twitter/twitter-logo.png'
  },
  {
    id:'2',
    title:'naruto',
    readStatus:true,
    imageSource:'https://mapstr-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/298ed6c57ada2a7560d24dabba452548_facebook-logo-F-1200x816.jpg'
  },
    {
    id:'3',
    title:'one piece',
    readStatus:true,
    imageSource:'https://mapstr-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/298ed6c57ada2a7560d24dabba452548_facebook-logo-F-1200x816.jpg'
  },
    {
    id:'4',
    title:'you name it',
    readStatus:true,
    imageSource:'https://mapstr-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/298ed6c57ada2a7560d24dabba452548_facebook-logo-F-1200x816.jpg'
  }
]

const target = animes.find(e=>e.id==='1');
target && (target.readStatus = true);


console.log(JSON.stringify(animes, null, 2));
```